# Register own errno and errno strings

Tags: c, linux

I'm intended to do a custom library for my typical functions. I want to implement them following the way of system calls (regarding errors).

Is there a way to register new/custom error numbers on a Linux system and its error string so an application works like system calls?

Comment: I don't think there is a mechanism for that.

Comment: You can do it, but probably you'll have to create your own functions to deal with it. The macros defined at `errno.h` are from the standard library, and I think it's not a good idea to mess with them

Comment: You'll should create your own (thread local) variable and your own set of constants and messages completely separate from `errno` and friends.

Comment: There are several POSIX functions like [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) that return custom, non-`errno` error codes, so you should not be afraid of implementing that in your own library, too. The main consideration should be whether the current supported set of [`errno` values](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is sufficiently descriptive, or not. For example, if your library is used to open a file that is not in a supported format, the function could return `EEXIST` or `ENOMSG`.